# AVAudioPlayer Distortion

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I have an iOS app which plays back some video using AVPlayer.  I also have an AVAudioPlayer instance I'm using to play sound effects when a button is tapped e.g. start play back and stop playback.  Both of these are "playing" at the same time.  This works fine, however the sound effect appears to be doubled-up (playing twice at the same time) or is overly loud.  To my ears it sounds like it's playing twice.  I'm triggering the sound effect like this:

```
- (void)playSFXForAction:(ActionSFX)action
{
    NSURL *sfx;
    switch (action) {
        case ActionSFXStartRecord:
            sfx = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"start-recording-fade" ofType:@"aiff"]];
            break;
        case ActionSFXStopRecord:
            sfx = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stop-recording-fade" ofType:@"aiff"]];
            break;
        case ActionSFXPreview:
            sfx = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"buzz" ofType:@"aiff"]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    NSError *error;
    self.sfxPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:sfx error:&error];
    [self.sfxPlayer play];
}
```

The distorted playback happens about 80% of the time.  Sometimes it plays the sound effect as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an unrelated retain cycle elsewhere in my code.  A quick check in the profiler showed there were two living instances of the VC handling the sounds effects.  Once the the retain cycle was fixed the distortion (double play) was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably two reason i think you are facing...

**(1)** It's just because you are calling the method all the time when you want to play the sound and the AVAudioPlayer allocating all the time with method.

you should put the alloc method any where else and then just play or stop or prepare to play function use.

so, the player alloc only one time but play sound as many times as you want.

**(2)** otherwise the problem is in sound file. just play that file in PC and check that.

Hope this helps. and not then just tell here with some more code.

Comment: The files are fine.  I have also tested with files from apps (not my own) which are working fine.  I have also tried moving the alloc and initialising with a single audio file to test.  Still get the distortion.

Comment: you are not getting me. i am trying to say, if you alloc the AVAudioPlayer then you have to release the AVAudioPlayer before allocating again and play the sound again. if the sound and device has no issue then only one thing should be there. and it is the AVAudioPlayer plays two times. so, you are hearing two sound instead of one sound. so, manage alloc and release then the problem will solved automatically.

Comment: I understand.  I'm alloc-ing once in viewDidLoad and initialise with one audio file.  I then call play on that single instance of AVAudioPlayer - the file never changes for my test.  I should be able to play AVAudioPlayer multiple times without releasing each time.